# Is there a minimal version of "npm install grunt"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

When I run npm install grunt I get, in my opinion, a heavily polluted project folder. In the folder node_modules there are libs like rimraf, coffescript and others I really don't want to use. Are these required for grunt itself to be able to run or are they only there for my convenience?

I would like some kind of "npm install grunt --minimal" to only install an absolute minimum of what's needed to be able to use grunt. I don't really like my project folder full of stuff that's not really my own code. I've googled the terms i can come up with, like "minimal grunt install", but only found the basic install tutorials.

Comment: Personally I use the `--dont-install-at-all-because-i-dont-want-slow-bloated-software-like-grunt` flag, which definitely minimizes the installed footprint.

Comment: @torazaburo so what do you suggest instead that fills the same need but doesn't bloat my project?

Comment: `make`. See https://algorithms.rdio.com/post/make/, or http://www.sitepoint.com/using-gnu-make-front-end-development-build-tool/. Granted, this falls in the territory of religious wars.

Comment: I fail to see why this has so many downvotes.  I've wasted a lot of time the past couple days trying out various setups.  The NPM installs seem to add up to 100+ megabytes.  What's more, it's not unusual for file/folder lengths to get too long for Windows.  I would LOVE a minimalist version.  My current attempt at a relatively small version includes over 86 THOUSAND files in my node_modules folder.  (26 dependencies in packages.json, 20 of which are dev only, and about 15 of which are gulp-related.  (rather than the grunt counterparts, just because I'm more familiar with gulp))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `node_modules` directory in a directory above your project's directory and do `npm install grunt` there. That way the modules are accessible but they aren't in your project's `node_modules` directory.

Another option is to use `npm install -g grunt` to install grunt globally.

Comment: But you failed to question the premise of the question, which is what exactly is the problem in having a busy `node_modules` directory, and what is the advantage in moving it one level up as you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not. Grunt is npm package and it has dependencies (this is normal). The fact is this dependencies don't pollute your project folder structure. It is normal to

- add node_modules to .gitignore and don't commit it
- install every npm package with `--save` flag (will write package to package.json) or `--save-dev` flag (will write package to package.json as package needed for development)
- commit package.json to repository. Thus, every team member can install all packages via `npm install` or `npm install --production`

As Dan said you can install grunt globally with -g flag but this will not solve your problem as every npm package that you install will have it own dependencies (and you'll probably think that it pollutes you folder structure as well)

You know, there are a lot of things that you need for development (or production). While installing apache (or something else) you don't say that is pollutes your file system (but it has own folder and so on).

Things don't pollute file structure if they don't exist in your project repository.

Comment: Makes sense: add node_modules to .gitignore and don't commit it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/)

pnpm creates the "deep" node_modules that you want

also saves disk space and network traffic : )

alternative: `npm install --legacy-bundling`
to produce a deep node_modules